# Login process for iOS

Tags: ios

On my final project, I am working for an application.

On the start up, there is a view controller for login process. The page contains two text fields and one button. One text field is for Username and another one is for Password.
I already connected to web service.

Now I want to set after the user fill both text fields with correct username and password, he needs to click the button to login. Here I want to implement an action to the button using if else statement.
Here what it should be:

```
if (username and password == YES)
go to next page
else (username and password == NO)
alert
```

Comment: It'll be great if you try it yourself and post your issue here. Don't look for someone to try it give you the exact code.

Answer (score 0):

Wazza, it ain't cool coming to stackoverflow to get your homework done.

UITextFiled has a property text, that is an NSString. The NSString has a property called length.

So you should face something like

```
- (void) loginAction:(id)sender
{
   if ([self.usernameTextField.text length] > 0 &&
       [self.passwordTextField.text length] > 0)
   {
      //Call webservice to login
   }
   else {
      //Show alert
   }
}
```

Comment: yes i am sorry about that. but i just need some help. thank you for your help though

Answer (score 0):

Here the steps your should follow:

- Open interface builder
- Right click your login button
- Choose the event you need, probably **Touch Up Inside**
- Drag it to File`S Owner and connect it with your IBAction that should look like this:

```c
- (IBAction)performLogin:(id)sender)
{
   // your logic here
}
```